# Compare CSV and conclusion of differences

Tags: csv, go

I started writing a program to compare two CSV files. After reading the documentation, I found a solution for I can't figure out how to print the differences from the second file since the function returns true/false

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("sms_in_max.csv")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    reader := csv.NewReader(file)
    records, _ := reader.ReadAll()
    fmt.Println(records)
    file2, err := os.Open("sms_out.csv")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    reader2 := csv.NewReader(file2)
    records2, _ := reader2.ReadAll()
    fmt.Println(records2)
    allrs :=reflect.DeepEqual(records, records2)
    fmt.Println(allrs)
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are to trying to do a diff. Reading through https://github.com/sergi/go-diff would probably get you to what you are looking for.

Comment: ok thansk I'll try to do

Comment: https://github.com/aswinkarthik/csvdiff hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The csv ReadAll() function returns slice of rows, where row is a slice of columns.
We can loop over the rows, and within a row, again loop over the columns and compare each column value.
Here is the code that prints all lines that have differences alongwith their line numbers.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("sms_in_max.csv")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    reader := csv.NewReader(file)
    records, _ := reader.ReadAll()
    fmt.Println(records)
    file2, err := os.Open("sms_out.csv")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    reader2 := csv.NewReader(file2)
    records2, _ := reader2.ReadAll()
    fmt.Println(records2)
    // allrs := reflect.DeepEqual(records, records2)
    // fmt.Println(allrs)

    // Prints lines at which there is difference
    for i := range records {
        diff := false
        for j := range records[i] {
            if records[i][j] != records2[i][j] {
                diff = true
                break
            }
        }
        if diff {
            fmt.Printf("Line %d: %v, %v\n", i+1, records[i], records2[i])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok thanks for your help, I'm just a newbie and therefore some simple things are not quite clear to me yet